# How to make a function that breaks a while loop that recording audio?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, audio-recording

I'm trying to make a python gui that has 2 buttons, one for recording audio and one to stop recording. the code runs on a raspberry pi 3 with a usb mic connected already.
I've done the recording button, and now I'm stuck on the stop recording button. 
the recording button runs in a while loop and I need that the 'stop' button will simply stop the while loop and save the recording to a file.

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time
import Tkinter
import ttk
import pyaudio
import wave

sense = SenseHat()
sense.clear()
snsui = Tkinter.Tk()
snsui.style = ttk.Style()
snsui.style.theme_use("classic")
snsui.geometry('130x150')
snsui.resizable(0,0)
#img = PhotoImage(file='/home/pi/sensehat/fav.ico')
#snsui.Tkinter.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)
#snsui.iconbitmap(default = "/home/pi/sensehat/image.png")
snsui.title("Sensors UI")
snsui.configure(background='light gray')
snsui.style.configure("TButton", padding=6, relief="flat",
background="turquoise",fieldbackground="black", foreground='royal blue')

form_1 = pyaudio.paInt16 # 16-bit resolution
chans = 1 # 1 channel
samp_rate = 44100 # 44.1kHz sampling rate
chunk = 4096 # 2^12 samples for buffer
record_secs = 3 # seconds to record
dev_index = 2 # device index found by p.get_device_info_by_index(ii)

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio() # create pyaudio instantiation
# create pyaudio stream
stream = audio.open(format = form_1,rate = samp_rate,channels = chans, \
                    input_device_index = dev_index,input = True, \
                    frames_per_buffer=chunk)

recording = True
def record(recording,s,a,c,ch,sr):
    if recording == False:
        recording = True
        print('start recording')
    else:
        recording = False
        print('trying to stop')

    frames = []

    # loop through stream and append audio chunks to frame array
    # ii in range(0,int((samp_rate/chunk)*record_secs)):
    while recording:
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        frames.append(data)

    print("finished recording")

    # stop the stream, close it, and terminate the pyaudio instantiation
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()

    wav_output_filename = 'test1.wav' # name of .wav file
    # save the audio frames as .wav file
    wavefile = wave.open(wav_output_filename,'wb')
    wavefile.setnchannels(chans)
    wavefile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(form_1))
    wavefile.setframerate(samp_rate)
    wavefile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wavefile.close()


B_recording = ttk.Button(snsui, text =" Record  ", command = record(recording,stream,audio,chunk,chans,samp_rate))
B_recording.pack()

snsui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create boolean flag which value is changed by stop button. Then just add if statement  to your while loop, and break when the flag have desired value.

Comment: how do I change the flag with another function?

Comment: Declare it outside of func body so it will be in scope of both functions. Then just use ‚=’

Comment: yeah but when I change the variable flag, it wont change it value for the other function as well...

Comment: It will, if the flag is global.